# How to do tokenization of text file in format UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, nltk

I want to do tokenization and have to create file containing tokenized words without stop words for sentiment analysis. I am trying with the code but it gives an error. The code is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
with open('Grey.txt', 'r') as text_file,open('step3.txt','w') as outFile:
text = text_file.read()
tokens=word_tokenize(str(text))
tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopset]
print(tokens)
outFile.write(str(tokens))
outFile.close()
```

and the error is:

```
(C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2) C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\Amazon Project>python sw.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sw.py", line 15, in <module>
tokens=word_tokenize(str(text))
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", 
line 109, in word_tokenize
return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", 
line 94, in sent_tokenize
return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 1237, in tokenize
return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line
1285, in sentences_from_text
return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 1276, in span_tokenize
return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line
1316, in _realign_boundaries
for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 311, in _pair_iter
for el in it:
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 1291, in _slices_from_text
if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 1337, in text_contains_sentbreak
for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 1472, in _annotate_second_pass
for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 310, in _pair_iter
prev = next(it)
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 577, in _annotate_first_pass
for aug_tok in tokens:
File "C:\Users\sama\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", 
line 542, in _tokenize_words
for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 12: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question, it can be copypasted

Comment: done............

Comment: Can you provide a sample portion from Grey.txt, and is it a UTF-8 or ASCII encoded text file?

Comment: sample portion can be tokenized.Actually I want to do tokenization of whole file.How can I share this file.please tell me..!!

Comment: You can use pastebin service to share files